# Picture miniaturized in PHP - dead link

Tags: php, upload

I have a php code who miniaturizes uploaded pictures by users.

This code is in the "miniature.php" file and it creates a file for each new picture.

After having uploaded the picture in another file (userform), it shows a preview (the miniature).

However, this is a dead link (I can see a little broken picture). The URL is like that :

http://www.mywebsite.com/annonce/miniature.php?pic=upload/XStmQFRY/PICTURE_UPLOADED.JPG&w_max=70&h_max=60

The url below, on the other hand, works and shows the original picture :

http://www.mywebsite.com/annonce/upload/XStmQFRY/PICTURE_UPLOADED.JPG

If you have an idea... do not hesitate!

Thank you :)

miniature.php code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


$taille = getimagesize($pic); 
$h_i = $taille[1]; 
$w_i = $taille[0]; 
        if($h_i >$h_max) 
    { 
    $convert=$h_max/$h_i; 
    $h_i=$h_max; 
    $w_i=ceil($w_i*$convert); 
    } 
    if($w_i >$w_max) 
    { 
    $convert=$w_max/$w_i; 
    $w_i=$w_max; 
    $h_i=ceil($h_i*$convert); 
    } ; 

$largeur = $w_i;
$hauteur = $h_i;

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($pic);

if($type == "1")
{
$img_in = imagecreatefromgif($pic);
}

if($type == "2")
{
$img_in = imagecreatefromjpeg($pic);
}

if($type == "3")
{
$img_in = imagecreatefrompng($pic);
}


$img_out = imagecreatetruecolor($largeur, $hauteur);
imagecopyresampled($img_out, $img_in, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($img_out), imagesy($img_out), imagesx($img_in), imagesy($img_in));
$t = imagejpeg($img_out);
echo $t;

?>
```

upload-file.php code :

```
<?php

$repdossier = $_GET['repdossier'];

$uploaddir = 'upload/'.$repdossier.'/';

$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 

$dir2 = opendir("upload/$repdossier/");

$getpages=0;

while ($File = readdir($dir2)){
                            if($File != "." && $File != ".." && $File != "" )
                              { $getpages++;

                              }

              }

closedir($dir2);

$calcul = $getpages;

if( @is_file($file) )
{
echo "error2";
}
else

{

if( $calcul >= 5)
{
echo "error1";
}

else

{



if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {
        echo "error";
}
}



}

?>
```

Javascript extract from all-index.php (shows the URL generated) :

```
                if(response==="success"){
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="miniature.php?pic=upload/<?php echo $repdossier; ?>/'+file+'&w_max=70&h_max=60" height="60" width="70" alt="" /><br />').addClass('success');
                }
```

Comment: 1. Don't put variables in quotes: `getimagesize($pic)`; 2. You have an error in the code. If you change the mime type to text, you'll see the error on opening the URL with the parameters. If now the script reports an error, your browser thinks it's an image. But it's text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I have the following error after having changed the mime type, having uploaded a picture and got the URL of its miniature : Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in (...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited the question, removed the buggy code and put in some unrelated Javascript.

The error is here:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$taille = getimagesize("$pic");
```

`$pic` must be a valid path to an **existing** picture. As of now, the variable is empty (undefined).

Comment: Sorry for this edit problem, I have modified this. I have deleted the quotes following your advise. But, the file is existing that is what I  do not understand...

Comment: @user1488152 you should check the the `$pic` variable (`echo $pic;`) and check if it really all good because the error is very concrete. One of the path is wrong, OR the permission is not readable on the file, so PHP cannot open it.

Comment: Ok, I have finally found : I have replaced $pic by $_GET['pic']... Thank you for your help! :)